# How to check which activity is currently running on android studio?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-studio

I am running my app on emulator. Is there anyway to see the current activity name in android studio . Like while I first launch the application I can see that I am on "MainActivity" after that if I do some action then I can see that I am on "AnotherActivity" .  Rather than writing code , I just want to see the current activity name while I am debugging my app on emulator or device

Comment: Technically what I meant  that rather than writing code I want to see in android studio . Does android studio has that feature ?

Comment: Use logcat to print the name of a new activity, whenever it is created (this.getClass().getSimpleName() ). Hope it solves your problem.

Comment: No, AndroidStudio does not have such feature. LogCat (as suggested by others) is the way to go.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I always create the TAG String into my Activities:

```
public final static String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
```

And then on the onCreate() just Log it:

```
Log.i(TAG, "I am here!");
```

Cheers!